# Apostrophe S help or explain

Tags: apostrophe

If `'s` shows possession then wouldn't it be used in the following sentences?

> I want to buy a car's door.
>  You have broken my computer's
>   screen.

Comment: You could, but we usually don't. There really is no *possession* involved. Just use "car" as a modifier for door, and "computer" as a modifier for screen. So just "car door" and "computer screen". These are objects well known by themselves.

Comment: @user3169 is correct. These phrases are idiomatic, so we don't use the possessive unless there is a particular reason to.

Comment: second sentence can also be expressed as _You have broken the screen of my computer_

Comment: Why not just flip the sentence around and say *You have broken my computer screen*? sounds much better

Comment: What do you mean there really is no possession involved? It is Terry's arm. Shows that he is the owner of his arm. But when it comes to car's door. It doesnt show that the car owns the door?

Comment: @user29882 Possessives don't always show ownership in a straightforward way. We would say *My car's front left tire* and **not** *My car left front tire*, but we say *My car door* and not *My car's door*. It's idiomatic; there's no real logic behind it.

Comment: @Era, "My car door" could be used for a door that you had lying in the back of your garage with no car attached. "My car's door" implies specifically a door that is attached to your car. I think the 2nd is at least as common as the first in ordinary conversation.

Answer (score 2):

Although there is a degree of idiomatic preference with regards to these phrases and the (lack of) apostrophe-s, there is a more subtle bit of schema that helps to inform this choice.

## Are we talking definite or indefinite?

The comment from @Era actually displays this. When we are talking about a *particular* tire on the *specific* car, thus referring to a definitive, well-defined object, Era uses the apostrophe-s construction:

> My car's front left tire.

But when @Era talks about a *not-individually-defined* door (the car could have one, but most have at least two, if not four or more), now referring to an indefinite object, the apostrophe-s construction is dropped.

> My car door.

## Possession or Modification?

@user3169 brings up the idea that possession isn't necessarily involved with respect to *car door* or *computer monitor*. A door can exist without ever being part of a car, and a monitor can exist without being part of a computer. Thus these adjectives do not add possession because they don't clearly define the object as belonging to (or in other words, as being possessed by) a specific object.

This doesn't mean they can't. Defining the tire as being THE front left tire of the car (as opposed to any old tire) assigns possession of that specific object to another specific object (This is ***my*** car. There are many like it, but *this* one is **mine**.)

## So, In Conclusion

Generally speaking: if the object is indefinite (just any old X), it doesn't use the apostrophe; if the object is definite (not just any X, ***my*** X), it uses the apostrophe. Exceptions abound (this is English, after all) but it's a good rule of thumb.

Comment: Would the same rule applies if I use it on the second sentence? Would it be My car's front left door.?

Comment: Absolutely. By describing the car as "_**your** car_" you've definitively identified the car in relation to you. As I said in aside in my answer, "_This is **my** car. There are many like it, but **this** one is **mine**._"